# Which better local data base in visual studio or data base from sql server with ClickOnce?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, clickonce

Maybe question is duplicate and is m first time to use ClickOnce.
I need to know which better way to deploy application with data base using ClickOnce.
Create a local data base using visual studio or create the data base separated with sql server?
And for note the data base contain a stored procedures.

Comment: Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements.

But; In my personal opinion, It's not a good idea to use LocalDB as the production database.

**Limitations.**

> - It does not support Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Window 2000.
> - It does not support WOW. LocalDB doesn't support installing 32-bit version on 64-bit Windows.
> - Allows only local connections. Only Named Pipes connections.
> - Only SQL Server 2012 Management Studio (on a computer updated with .NET Framework 4.0.2) can be used to manage LocalDB. SQL Server
>     Management Studio of previous versions of SQL Server cannot be used.
> - Visual Studio 2010 RTM does not support LocalDB.
> - It does not run on mobile devices.
> - Database size limit: 10 GB.
> - LocalDB cannot be used as a merge replication subscriber.
> - It does not support FileStream. FileStream is not supported on user instances.
> - Limited to use one CPU.
> - T-SQL Debugging cannot be used when connected to a LocalDB instance. For more information, click here.
> - SQL Server Profiler cannot be used against a LocalDB instance.
> - It does not support JDBC.
> - It supports ADO.NET but does not support ADO.
> - The system databases, SQL Server error logs,  are stored in the AppData folder in the user profile. Usually, they will be located on
>     C:\Users\youruseraccount\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
>     Local DB\Instances\v11.0.
> - It does not support partitioned tables. **
> - Linked Servers are not supported. For more information, click here.
> - The instance collation for LocalDB is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS by default and cannot be changed.
> - LocalDB automatic instances fail to create on roaming user profiles.

[Source Article](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/SQLServer2012_0004.htm)

[SQL Express v LocalDB v SQL Compact Edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jerrynixon/sql-express-v-localdb-v-sql-compact-edition)